# "Spark 2.4.3 S3 MultiObjectDeleteException " in sparklyr

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark, sparklyr

I am really struggling with this error which I keep getting whenever I try to do the following . And I tried all the suggestions provided in the old links as well , but in vain.

```
spark_write_csv(final_data_3,path = "mypath",header = T,mode = "overwrite",infer_schema=F)
```

## This is the error I get

```
Spark 2.4.0 S3 MultiObjectDeleteException
```

I was reading through old answers for similar problem and it suggested it should below configuration in settings to avoid this error .

I added this and I also used true in place of false in script , still am getting same error .

```
hconf %>% sparklyr::invoke("set","fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable","false")
```

## Any suggestions to address this error ?

Comment: upgrade to hadoop 3.3.1 binaries and consistent aws sdk, rerun and attach the stack trace. the we will see where to go from there. It may be your iAM role just doesn't have delete permissions on the path

Comment: I am using winutils file as a proxy for Hadoop , is there any way to update this ?